# Java. Не работают относительные ссылки в веб проекте Spring MVC 4 + Glassfish

Tags: java, spring-mvc, glassfish

В java недавно, пытаюсь разобраться c какой стороны подойти к вопросу.

У меня glassfish по умолчанию запускает проект с корнем урла вида "`http://localhost:8080/myProjectFolderName`".

Проблема в том, что относительные ссылки типа href="page" ведут на урл относительно домена "`http://localhost:8080/page`" а не поддиректории  "`http://localhost:8080/myProjectFolderName/page`".

Переход относительно директории проекта происходит только если последним символом урла стоит слеш.

Я попробовал и погуглил разное, и вижу только 3 решения:

1. Ипользование абсолютных ссылок(ужасный вариант);
2. Какой-нибудь редирект с урла "`http://domain/projectFolderName`" на вариант со слешем в конце (тоже как-то не очень, но буду рад объяснению и этого, куда копать. я попробовал пару вариантов, с ходу не заработало, решил сначала совет услышать);
3. Настройка сервера приложений на запуск проекта в корне домена. Если это лучший вариант, то что же, для любого маленького тестового проектика создавать новый локальный домен?

Как быть?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для навигации при помощи ссылок есть 4 метода

```
<html>
 <body>
  <a href="./test">test</a>
  <a href="testEmpty">testEmpty</a>
  <a href="../testParent">testParent</a>
  <a href="/testRoot">testRoot</a>
 <body>
</html>
```

1. `./` - означает поиск в том же каталоге
2. Если не указан протокол, то аналогично пункту 1, но без явного указания `./`.
3. `../` - поиск в родительском каталоге
4. `/` - поиск в корневом каталоге

Учитывая пункт 2, у тебя присутствуют ошибки в утверждении

> Проблема в том, что относительные ссылки типа href="page" ведут на урл
>   относительно домена "http://localhost:8080/page" а не поддиректории
>   "http://localhost:8080/myProjectFolderName/page".

Что касательно контекста приложения (war'ника), то браузер не имеет стандартизированных возможностей узнать о нём. Поэтому тебе надо явно передавать его с сервера. Для его получения нужно использовать [HttpServletRequest.getContextPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29). [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21046620/5506820) хороший пример что к чему. Чтобы получить `HttpServletRequest` в `spring-mvc`-компоненте достаточно просто указать в функции параметр этого типа и `spring` внедрит его при вызове функции. Пример [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18690960/5506820)

Answer (score 1):

Просто нужен ContextPath как префикс, он укажет, откуда сейчас все танцует.
В конфиге для Freemarker так можно:

```
viewResolver.setRequestContextAttribute("rc");
```

И тогда в любом темлейте он доступен через

```
<#assign contextPath=rc.getContextPath()>
```

и тогда во всех объектах, где это нужно

```
<a href="${contextPath}/logout/">
```

В других view типах бывает rc доступен сразу, без дополнительных настроек (нужно указать какой вы используете).